# React.js: Unable to to get the updated state back in App using redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In the app => **[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-app-d6q7tv?file=/src/App.js)** the `redux-saga` is getting executed, but I'm unable to get the updated state back in my `App` component. I'm unable to identify why this application is having this behavior.

**productReducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS } from "../types/action";

const initialState = {
  products: []
};

export const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      state.products = action.products;
      break;
    default:
    // do nothing
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutate states should be avoided. We must update the state immutably. See [Reducers and Immutable Updates](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates)

> In order to update values immutably, your code must make copies of existing objects/arrays, and then modify the copies.

```
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS } from '../types/action';

const initialState = {
    products: [],
};

export const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            // state.products = action.products
            return { ...state, products: action.products };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76719051-5q95pc)